# Cassandra: Making range queries

Tags: nosql, cassandra, command-line-interface, thrift, cql

I understand that you can make range queries on column names.
Example: Get all columns whose names are between 100-200.

While I have found many examples on how to create a column-family in such a way, I have not found an example of making such a query in CLI or CQL.

I am looking for something like: `GET journals['bob'] WHERE column-names BETWEEN 100 AND 200`

Does such a statement exist in CLI or CQL?
Or do I have to resort to thrift?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [CQL](http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.0/references/cql/SELECT#synopsis) the query would be:

```
select 100..200 from journals where name = 'bob';
```

Note that this syntax is changing in CQL 3.0 to something like:

```
select value from journals where name = 'bob' and column > 100 and column < 200;
```